# How to debug android codes after loops in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have found my app returned error after a for loop.
Are there any tricks for me to just run through the for-loop and then debug?
I have studied some posts saying that using Ctrl+R could help.
However my latest version eclipse cannot found such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Step debugging in Eclipse

mark a break point in the code where you want ( mark at the blue line as shown with a small blue circle)

[image]

then run->Debug Configuration and start the app

and when the program starts it will stop at that line where you put break point.

[image]

just dont forget to change from JAva or DDMS to Debug

[image]

also you can see various stepping code things in run menu while debugging

[image]

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

1.use `Log.i()` or `System.out.println()` to print something.
2.just see debug information in logcat
3.reduce loop times or replace loop with other simple code, then run the app again

Comment: So, there is no function for Eclipse run through the codes and start debugging from specific line?